# Sonar build stability plugin marks unstable builds as failed

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using the cool Build Stability plugin for Sonar. I am importing Jenkins build results into Sonar. The Jenkins build I am tracking has only Unstable and Failed results, no Success yet (all tests have not passed yet). This makes the result in Sonar a bit misleading as it displays all builds as failed.

Is it possible to change this in Sonar somehow? I.e. that Unstable builds would be displayed as Green, or that Unstable builds would have a separate color in Sonar, e.g. Yellow?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is an open request : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1608. Feel free to vote for it.